# How do I set up triggers to make interactable objects in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a script that when placed on a object with a collider will allow the player to interact with it. I want to use triggers to do this. At the moment I just want it to print "interact" to the console once it reaches a certain range, for some reason it is not doing that. I even tried to just set it to player.position =! null and player.position==null and in both cases it wouldnt print to the console.

here is the interactable code

```
void update(){

        float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, transform.position); 
        if (distance <= radius)
        {
            Debug.Log("INTERACT");
        }

} 
public void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) {
    isFocused = true;
    player = other.GetComponent<Transform>();

}
```

and here is the code for the player to interact with the collider

```
public void OnTriggerStay(Collider interactionCollider){
    interactable = interactionCollider.GetComponent<Interactable>();
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("f")){
        if(interactable!=null){
            Debug.Log("yay");
        }
    }
}
```

The "Yay" does print when I hit f and I am in the other colider.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is 99% correct as it is. However, I would recommend having the interaction trigger script on your interactable object instead of the player.This will allow you to have multiple interactions all with different input keycodes rather than only 1 on the player.

If you are checking for a certain distance it is more clear to have use the Enter and Exit functions for colliders / triggers. Then in your Update() you only need to check if the player is in the collider / trigger with a simple boolean comparison.

In your collider / trigger enter and exit it is more efficient to use the object's variables that was sent as the parameter. This allows for simple selection of what is being compared and doesn't require an unnecessary function call, GetComponent<>();

Some example code below for reference.

```
//Flag used to tell if the object can be interacted with or not.
    public bool isInteractable = false;


    void Update()
    {
        //Checks if the player is in the collider and also if the key is pressed.
        if(isInteractable && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            //personalized code can go in here when activated.
            Debug.Log("Interact");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is called when there is an object that enters the collider's borders.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other"></param>
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        //Compares the tag of the object entering this collider.
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            //turns on interactivity 
            isInteractable = true;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Is called when there is an object that leaves the collider's borders.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other"></param>
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        //compares the tag of the object exiting this collider.
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            //turns off interactivity 
            isInteractable = false;
        }
    }
```